# I don't know why this error appears. "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb, apache-commons-dbcp, james

It worked fine in a Windows environment, but an error occurs in Linux Ubuntu.

my wrapper.log

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 | Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:125)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.installDBDictionary(DataSourceFactory.java:249)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       ... 89 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       ... 94 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(ConfigurationImpl.java:346)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.instantiateAll(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:1963)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:665)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:207)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2024/03/19 15:11:11 |       ... 71 more
STATUS | wrapper  | 2024/03/19 15:11:13 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Setting up James server.

my james-database.properties

```
database.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database_mail
database.username=mail
database.password=mypassword!

vendorAdapter.database=MYSQL

openjpa.streaming=false
```

Java SE: Version 17
I've done all the environmental variables as well.
I tried using version 21 and version 17.

I also put the MariaDB driver file in the lib folder.

Java environment variables and driver files are normal. They work fine in Windows environments, but not in Linux environments.

Comment: what lib folder? Instead of having an external jar/driver file maybe you can use maven to set it up for you. Also, it could be that the driver file on ur windows is up to date, but the one on the linux server is outdated or something

Comment: According to the document, when you put a jar file in the lib folder, it automatically fetches that file.
So if you put the mariadb driver file in lib, it will automatically load the driver.

Comment: only you know what document it is and what lib folder you are talking about is. you are not clear enough

Comment: JAMES config : https://james.apache.org/server/3/config.html

JAMES system : https://james.apache.org/server/3/config-system.html